# Second call to Mathjax typeset function from jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, mathjax, typeset

I am trying to view the equations typed in HTML textbox (in Tex) as mathematical equations using **MathJax**.
If the equations are not correctly viewed, I need to edit the equations and review it, in mathematical equations.

For the first time, it works fine. **But after the editing is performed the Mathjax typeset command shows errors**.
Requesting you to please go through it, and suggest possible error(s).

The HTML I am using is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Equation Edit
        </title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
        <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3.0.0/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <strong> Here is the result :<br></strong>
        <input type="text" id=input value="\(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\)">
        <div id="qPreview"></div>
            <button id="check">Click</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

The script I am using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var eq;
            $("#check").click(function(){
                eq=document.getElementById("input").value;
                document.getElementById("qPreview").innerHTML=eq;
                MathJax.typeset(qPreview[0]);
            });

        </script>
```

It shows the following error for the second time when I click the button:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at l.append (tex-mml-chtml.js:1)

I am new to javascript. I thank you in advance, for sharing any error or suggestion for the code to work properly.

Comment: This works perfectly fine. Try after removing the dangling </div> after the button

Comment: That was one of the errors. Thanks for pointing it out. The problem is, the MathJax.typeset command is not working after the button is pressed more than once.
I have edited the </div> problem.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem, and I think it might be a bug. Anyway, it can be solved by rendering the equation to an auxiliary "p" tag inside your "qPreview" div, then deleting and re-creating this tag when the equation is modified. For example:

```js
$("#check").click(function(){
    $("#qPreview").empty().append("<p>" + $("#input").val() + "</p>");
    MathJax.typeset(["#qPreview"]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3.0.0/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<strong> Here is the result :<br></strong>
<input type="text" id=input value="\(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\)">
<div id="qPreview"></div>
<button id="check">Click</button>
```

Some notes to your code:

- If you are using jQuery, then you can make your life easier using it instead of `getElementById` function: you can write `$("#input").val()` instead of `document.getElementById("input").value`
- The `qPreview` variable is not defined, so `MathJax.typeset(qPreview[0])` would result in an error.
- `MathJax.typeset()` expects either no arguments or a list as an argument. (That's why `"#qPreview"` is in brackets in my code). For more info, see the [documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/typeset.html#typesetting-math-in-a-web-page):

  > Both functions take an optional argument, which is an array of elements whose content should be processed. An element can be either an actual DOM element, or a CSS selector string for an element or collection of elements. Supplying an array of elements will restrict the typesetting to the contents of those elements only.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It resolved my problem.

Comment: @Asheshanand Acharya, please accept the answer if it resolved your problem. I had this same problem (first time formula was rendered correctly, but after that LaTex string is displayed as-is). I fixed it by calling .empty() and then .append() as hakkelt suggested.

Comment: I don't get it, the solution works for me only if I append $("#input").val()  to the div, but if I put any other text in the right format, it fails. What the hell?